# Print response headers in jsp

Tags: jsp, http-headers, response

I am trying to understand the response header concept in j2ee.I am setting header valus in servlet.Now how can confirm that header got changed or added. 
Is it possible to print response headers in jsp.
If yes then how ?.

Comment: Just call your servlet and "sniff" the response using Tamper plugin for FF or similar tool

Comment: @alfasin thanks a lot.It solved my problem.Now I am using tamper plugin.It is an great tool.I was not aware of this.